# Jijna2 recursion always seems to produce depth exceeded error

Tags: python, recursion, jinja2

I have never used jinja recursion before but it seems like it should be relatively understandable. I am having trouble rendering data in this format with the template engine. The following python code is a good example of what I am trying to reproduce in Jinja:

```py
layers = {
    'groups': {
        'lower': {
            'groups': {},
            'layers': [{
                'layer_name': 'left #1',
            },
            {
                'layer_name': 'right #1',
            }]
        },
        'upper': {
            'groups': {},
            'layers': [{
                'layer_name': 'left',
            },
            {
                'layer_name': 'right',
            }]
        }
    },
    'layers': [{
        'layer_name': 'Background',
    }]
}

def printDict(_dict):
    for layer in _dict['layers']:
        print(layer['layer_name'])

    for group in _dict['groups']:
        print(group)
        printDict(_dict['groups'][group])

    printDict(layers)
```

I try to make the template code as similar to the above working logic as possible, like so:

```
<ul>
    {% for node in layers recursive %}
        {% set outer_loop = loop %}
        {% if node == "layers" %}
            {% for layer in layers[node] %}
                <li>{{layer['layer_name']}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% elif node == "groups" %}
            {% for group in layers[node] %}
                <li><b>{{group}}</b></li>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    {{ outer_loop(layers[node][group]) }}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, each time I get a 'recursion depth exceeded'. This is very frustrating to debug because there is not any easy debugger or method to print values during the looping. Can anyone spot the logic flaw?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I ended up figuring out a working method. The issue is that Jinja has very strange variable scoping. Unlike python, inside of the loops the variable is not reassigned and it continues to use the original global variable, which leads to the infinite loop condition. I solved this by using ".items()" method on each recursive call (and the original call, to keep consistent) which creates a new variable in the local scope (I believe, maybe it also just overwrites a variable in the global scope, but either way it works)

```
<ul>
    {% for key, v in layers,items() recursive %}
        {% set outer_loop = loop %}
        {% if key == "layers" %}
            {% for layer in v %}
                <li>{{layer['layer_name']}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% elif key == "groups" %}
            {% for group in v %}
                <li><b>{{group}}</b></li>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    {{ outer_loop(v[group].items()) }}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```